# Function breaks mid-way due to row deletion?

Tags: php, pdo, sql-delete

I can't seem to figure out what's going on! The script runs perfect, until the files have to delete.

```
function myFunction($db) {
            if (isset($_POST['deleteProject'])) {
                $stmtOne = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM projects WHERE title =  :title');
                $stmtOne->execute([
                    'title' => str_replace('+', ' ', $_GET['project'])
                ]);

                $stmtTwo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE title = :title');
                $stmtTwo = $db->execute([
                    'title' => str_replace('+', ' ', $_GET['project'])
                ]);

                foreach ($stmtTwo as $row) {
                    $files = glob('project_images/'.$row['id'].'{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
                    foreach($files as $file) {
                        if(is_file($file))
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
                header ('Location: cms.php?delete=t');
            }
```

My question is; Does this function break mid-way due to the deletion of the row? Or is it due to faulty code? I'm not sure what I can try.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "break"... any error messages (on screen or in logs)? Some files deleted but not all? No files deleted? Wrong files deleted?

Comment: @Saty There's no explicit call to `bindParam()`, but instead an array has been passed to `execute()`. That part is fine.

Comment: it breaks because first you delete from the DB then you try to select again what you just deleted. Select first, get your ids to use on the filesystem delete, try to delete from the database, if successfull delete from the filesystem

Comment: Can you just confirm that you are doing `str_replace()` on `+` because the string has an _explicit_ `+` and not that you are trying to manually `urldecode()`  the string from $_GET after spaces have been encoded to `+`?  PHP will automatically urldecode `$_GET` (and the other input superglobals) to return the original string without `+`; if that's what you're attempting to do, it is unnecessary.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh so I don't need the `str_replace()`? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexAndrei Thanks, you've answered it!! I can't help but feel a bit stupid now!

Comment: @Rahul Check the output from `var_dump($_GET)` - if you do not see `+` there which you want to remove, the no you do not need it. `urldecode()` is implicitly called on `$_GET,$_POST,$_COOKIE` so even if the URL contains `?key=val+with+space`, `$_GET['key']` will contain `val with space`.